# Set permission for cloud run to access POST method

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I deployed my project using the cloud run service of google. I have added a role for **allUser** is **Cloud Run Invoker**. With this permission, I can call service with the GET method. But I can not use the POST method. Please help me. Thanks

Comment: Can you share the error you are receiving when doing the POST request? Also how are you doing the post? More information will be useful in order to be able to help you further

Comment: Cloud Run’s IAM-based authentication/authorization does not distinguish between GET vs POST or any other HTTP method for that matter. It's likely that something’s wrong on your side.

Comment: @bhito
`
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>405 Method Not Allowed</title>
<h1>Method Not Allowed</h1>
<p>The method is not allowed for the requested URL.</p>`

Comment: It's a message from your webserver, not a Cloud Run message!

Answer (score 1):

If you reach your Cloud Run with the GET HTTP verb, you can reach it with POST also. The security layer of Cloud Run, performed by Google Front End, is only in charge to check the security, not the type of access.

You shouldn't receive a 403 or 401 error, maybe something like 501 Not Implemented. Check your webserver and validate outside Cloud Run that it accepts POST request.

Comment: Thanks @guillaume blaquiere for you comment, I checked my application on localhost, it runs, and i have run it on compute engine with nginx, it still run, but when i used cloud run  and cloud build for auto deployment, it not access.

Comment: On cloud shell (or any environment with docker installed) can you perform this command `docker run -p 8080:8080 gcr.io/<project id>/<containter name> -e <list of your required env var>`. Then test your container on the port 8080. You will have the same behavior as Cloud Run. Something happening in your container build. Share your code if you want more help

Comment: Thanks @guillaume blaquiere. It's my mistake, i fixed it,  I call from other service with http, but cloud run using https, so it raise that error message. Before, I used Compute Engine with Nginx using both http and https